# Vertically Center a TextView to the right of a FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="5dip"
            android:minWidth="5dip"
            android:maxWidth="20dip"
            android:maxHeight="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/changeinscore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0.00"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:shadowRadius="7"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/background"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to vertically center the middle TextView to the right of the FrameLayout, as the changeinscore TextView is inside the FrameLayout, if that makes sense. Currently it's off center because the centerVertical is centering it in the entire RelativeLayout, not specifically to the FrameLayout, if I understand it correctly. Basically I want the middle textview to be empty but to actually anchor other textviews so I can have 2 textviews slightly offcenter to the framelayout/imageview.

If I follow what San says, here is the result, but not exactly what I want
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got what you wanted and here is my sample of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/im"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/changeinscore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:shadowRadius="7"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/background"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="5dip"
            android:minWidth="5dip"
            android:maxWidth="20dip"
            android:maxHeight="20dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/frame"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Aldnoah.Zero"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-slab"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bottom Text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

And the layout looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/d89ak8)

Comment: The problem is this won't work because I'm essentially going to use the TextView to anchor other TextViews to be near the center of the FrameLayout. And it didn't center anyway.

Comment: Maybe you should add `match_parent` attribute to your root `RelativeLayout`, and `FrameLayout` so that every view inside your root is fully occupied and assigning it a `centerVertical` attribute might make more sense. Provided if these attributes wont hinder your design.

Comment: I think it'll mess up the design because this is the recyclerview item layout.

Comment: You'd have to give it a shot to see if it will mess up the layout or else I presume that you should just use a different layout style to create your design.

Comment: See the added image to see what happens when I do that. (It doesn't work).

Comment: And please make sure that you remove the `match_parent` attribute from your root. Its my bad, should've known.

Comment: Wait this doesn't work exactly as I hoped, please see new image in main post. While the middle TextView is indeed centered, the problem is it's not letting the other textviews display just above it or just below it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128310/discussion-between-san-and-user2923535).

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know that I took your solution and adapted it to be exactly what I needed, look in the chat to see what I ended up doing if you're interested.